# Use buttons within a JFrame from another application, without giving focus to the java application?

Tags: java, swing

Is there any way I can set my java application to not take focus when I use a button from it's interface.

My intention is to have a frame that is always on top, which users can use while in other applications to trigger various tasks - but I don't want them to then switch to my application on doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way of communicating with the non-focused GUI via core Java. Likely you'll need to use OS specific JNI or JNA code or (my choice) an OS-specific scripting hot-key trapping language like AutoIt if this were for a Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can set my java application to not take focus when I use a button from it's interface.

```
frame.setFocusableWindowState( false );
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a floating toolbar.  I think what you are looking or is [`setFocusableWindowState`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setFocusableWindowState%28boolean%29).

From the API:

> Setting a Window's focusability state to false is the standard
>   mechanism for an application to identify to the AWT a Window which
>   will be used as a floating palette or toolbar, and thus should be a
>   non-focusable Window.

Comment: This would work well if it was all in one application package - while the window does not focus the overall application does (on Mac OSX atleast). Meaning I can't use any of the other application's hotkeys without tabbing back into it.